# Is the set of probability measures with strong convergence compact and/or metrizable?

Tags: general-topology, probability-theory, measure-theory, compactness, polish-spaces

Given a compact metrizable space $X$ endowed with its Borel sigma algebra, call $P$ the set of probability measures on the resulting measurable space.
Endow $P$ with the topology of strong convergence i.e. a net $(m_{\alpha})$ converges to a point $m$ iff $m_{\alpha}(B)$ converges to $m(B)$ for any measurable set B.
I would like to know whether P is compact and/or Polish. Of course we know that this is the case with weak convergence.

Answer (score 5):

No. Let $X=[0,1]$, $\mu_n=\delta_{1/n}$. Then $(\mu_n)$ has no strongly convergent subsequence.

(If $\mu_{n_j}\to\mu$ strongly then $\mu((0,1])=1$ but $\mu((1/n,1])=0$ for all $n$.)

Comment: Thank you very much for the counterexample, how about separability and metrizability?

Comment: A similar argument should show that $\{\delta_x : x \in X\}$ is an uncountable discrete set and therefore $P$ is not separable.

Comment: More specifically, for each $x \in X$ let $U_x = \{\mu \in P : \mu(\{x\}) > 1/2\}$.  Then the $U_x$ are uncountably many disjoint open sets.

Comment: Ok the argument for non separability is clear, thank you very much.